# Laravel 5: How to create a custom attribute for a collection, then sort with it

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'd like to do complex sorting on the results of a model.

E.g. I have `\App\Classes::where(something)`, and from there I'd like to append an additional attribute for each class, then sort using that attribute, i.e. (inspired by the approach in https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/is-there-any-way-to-add-attribute-to-objects-in-collection)

```
$classes = \App\Classes::where(something)
foreach ($classes as &$class) {
        $classes['custom_score'] = some logic that changes per $class;
}
$classes_sorted = $classes->orderBy('custom_score')
```

But this code gives me the

> SQL error: "Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'custom_score' in 'order clause'"

I don't want to actually write to the database for this custom_score, since it will change often and uniquely, with every user interaction.

What would be a good solution?

Thanks a lot in advance..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`transform()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-transform) collection method:

```
$collection->transform(function($i) {
    $i->custom_score = // Some logic here
    return $i;
});
```

Comment: Thanks Alexey, this is very close to what I'd like to achieve. So it from my understanding I need it to be in a collection format for this to work (i.e. $collection = \App\Classes::where(x)->get(), then apply your code). However, afterwards I'd like to paginate the results (i.e. $collection->paginate(20)), but I can't do this, since I think pagination only works on models directly, rather than on collections (i.e. I get the "Method paginate does not exist." error). Any suggestions? Thanks again

Comment: @user6122500 you could [create Paginator manually](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/pagination#manually-creating-a-paginator). Where and how will you use the additional property?

Comment: I was going to orderBy or sortByDesc $classes, using this 'custom_score', then display the sorted $classes in a view (a catalogue page basically)

Answer (score 1):

> append an additional attribute for each class

but in your code you are appending the value to `$classes`. Add the value to `$class`

```
$classes = \App\Classes::where(something)->get();

foreach ($classes as &$class) {
    $class['custom_score'] = some logic that changes per $class;
}
```

Plus a [collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#available-methods) does not have `orderBy` method instead you need to use `sortBy()`

```
$classes_sorted = $classes->sortBy('custom_score')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an [accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-mutators) on your model like:

```
public function getCustomScoreAttribute() {
       // return some logic per 
}
```

That makes `custom_score` accessible on your model.

Answer (score 0):

Use [sortBy()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-sortby) collection method :

```
$classes = \App\Classes::where(something)->get();
foreach ($classes as &$class) {
    $classes->custom_score = some logic that changes per $class;
}
$classes_sorted = $classes->sortBy('custom_score')
```